# Function print in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need something to print the function `draw()` in one line for all `i` in the loop. I've searched here, but couldn't find anything.

```
def many(n):
   b = str(n)
   c=[]
   x=[]
   for digit in b:
    c.append (int(digit))
   for i in range(len(c)):
      draw(c[i])
```

Comment: What is in the `draw` function?

Comment: Use the **map** function to apply **draw** to each element of **c**.